# Помогите разобраться с пунктуацией

Tags: пунктуация

Является ли, в данном случае, "если что" вводным?

– Ты мне *если что* поможешь?

Поглощает ли тире запятую?

– Странная… – провожая взглядом девушку, тихо хмыкнул он, повторяя случайно услышанное *прозвище, – как* за глаза называли её некоторые одногруппники.

Нужна ли запятая перед "или"?

Теперь оставался один вопрос: соврать и *продолжить, или* нет?

Как правильно оформить восклицание в тексте?

И она, *с упёртостью «я это сделаю»,* пыталась подвинуть не отодвигаемое.

Хотя может быть так?

И она, *с упёртостью – «я это сделаю!» –* пыталась подвинуть не отодвигаемое.

Заранее спасибо всем, кто сможет мне помочь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

– Ты мне, если что, поможешь? "Если что" (если что случится) - неполное придаточное предложение.

```
Поглощает ли тире запятую?
```

– Странная… – провожая взглядом девушку, тихо хмыкнул он, повторяя случайно услышанное прозвище, – как за глаза называли её некоторые одногруппники.

Не думаю. Если что и убирать, то тире, потому что вводное предложение (как за глаза называли её некоторые одногруппники) отделяется, как правило, запятыми. В этом случае тире возможно, потому что хочется ярче выделить концовку, сделать больше паузу. Может быть, здесь имеет случай постановка запятой и тире как единого знака. Но запятую убирать не стоит, она закрывает деепричастный оборот.

```
 Нужна ли запятая перед "или"?
```

Теперь оставался один вопрос: соврать и продолжить(,) или нет?

Я бы не поставила, потому что НЕТ относится к паре "соврать и продолжить". Можно, конечно, ИЛИ НЕТ принять за присоединение, но я его не вижу, обычные однородные члены.

```
 Как правильно оформить восклицание в тексте?
```

Второй вариант мне нравится больше, но с поправочкой. Если Вы поставили одну запятую, выделив пояснительный оборот, нужно ставить и вторую:
И она, с упёртостью – «я это сделаю!», – пыталась подвинуть не отодвигаемое.А можно и без запятых, читая без паузы: И она с упёртостью – «я это сделаю!» – пыталась подвинуть не отодвигаемое. Я бы предпочла такую расстановку знаков препинания.

А "неотодвигаемое" почему раздельно? Это в тексте так? Противопоставления нет, зависимых слов нет. По-моему, здесь нет условий писать раздельно, тем более, что оканчивается на -мый.

Comment: И она с упёртостью – «я это сделаю!» – пыталась подвинуть не отодвигаемое. Это просто неполное предложение, а только его часть. Вот, оно полностью: Правда, эта «скала» была наощупь тёплой и помягче, и она с упёртостью – «я это сделаю!» – пыталась подвинуть не отодвигаемое. (Речь идёт о большом животном)

Comment: Такая пунктуация  корректна. На ощупь-раздельно,неотодвигаемое - слитно